# Endpoint working in postman but failing test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

I'm trying to test a delete endpoint, which is working when testing manually in Postman but it's failing my test with 500 error.

```py
def test_delete_notification(self):
        deleted_notification = URL + 'delete/' + str(self.notification.id)

        response = requests.delete(
            url=deleted_notification,
        )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        notifications = NotificationX.objects.filter(recipient_id=self.user.id,
                                                     deleted=True)

        self.assertEqual(len(notifications), 1)
```

This is the test inside the TestCase. I'm using Django TestCase.

This is the code for the delete method:

```py
    def delete(self, request, notification_id):
        notification = NotificationX.objects.get(id=notification_id)
        notification.deleted = True

        serialized_notification = NotificationSerializer(notification)

        return Response(serialized_notification.data)
```

The URL:

```py
path('delete/<uuid:notification_id>',
     cls.as_view({'delete': 'delete'}, name='user_delete_notification')),
```

This is the error that is failing the test:

```py
NotificationsCenter matching query does not exist.
F......S....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_delete_notification (notifications_center.notifications.tests.test_endpoints.TestNotificationsEndpoints)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andressa/MEGAsync/Company Hero/repositories/hero-django/smart-store/smartstore/notifications_center/notifications/tests/test_endpoints.py", line 78, in test_delete_notification
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 500 != 200
```

How can I fix this problem and make my test pass?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out this issue? I am dealing with an almost identical issue right now. Mine is a GET verb, works just fine in Postman and fails with a 500 on the UnitTest.